# PHP: Difference between -f and browser output

Tags: php, command-line, odbc

I am trying to run PHP this code to test a connection to my database:

```
<?php
$dsn = "database name";       
$username = "user name";              
$password = "";         
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $username, $password);

$q = "select version()";
$r = odbc_exec($conn, $q);
echo odbc_result($r, "Version") . "Hi";
?>
```

When I run it with php's -f option it will give me the expected output:

> Database Version  + Hi

But when I open it in my web browser it will only output:

> Hi

My apache error log tells me

> Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

But it should be ...

So my question is, why that? I suspect it could have to do something with Permissions for my odbc driver or so .... but I don't know where to start...

Edit: Setup Process of the Web Server:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

I hope thats about what I did for the web server
Afterwards I changed the Username inside apache2.conf (httpd.config) to my actual user, as I want it to run with my current useraccount (it is note that I didn't change it in "/etc/apache2/envvars".

I am running on Ubuntu 16

Comment: Turn on display_errors and error_reporting (`ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`) and remove the error-supresssing (`@`-symbol) before `odbc_connect`. Then update your question with error-messages you got. Most likely you connection failed and `odbc_result` returns `false`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added the two lines and removed the "@". Unfortunately it didn't change any output (neither -f or web browser). Do I have to view another file to see errors?

Comment: Well, normally this will show all errors in the browser. Can you verify the value of `$conn` with a `var_dump($conn);` just after the `odbc_connect`-line? Should be `false` on connection-error or `resource(number)` on succes.

Comment: hm yes, it is indeed "false".  But how can they differ in one and the same file ? My apache error log tells me "Data source name not found, and no default driver specified". But it should be ...

Comment: What's the underlying database? Could it have user specific permissions bound to it?

Comment: It is a Vertica database. But as far as I use an ODBC connection, it should not bring up permission problems. Also I have this problem only in Ubuntu right now, (maybe I am missing some packages?) It is working for Centos.

Comment: Also when you execute the script on the terminal, it should be a message something like `Vertica Analytic Database v6.1.2-0 Hi`

Comment: Just for the record, did you installed the Vertica odbc driver on your Ubuntu machine, right?

Comment: Yes, you both are right. The problem most likely lies in my web server setup and its ODBC settings ... I will update the way I set it up in the question

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution now: 
Somehow the environment setting I have declared are not used by the apache user. Because of this he is having problems to find the ODBC.ini file. To solve it, I added the following 2 lines into my php connection file :

```
putenv('ODBCINI=/demo_application/Build/odbc.ini');
putenv('ODBCSYSINI=/demo_application/Build/');
```